# Can we convert iOS native app to web app in xcode

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

Is there any way to convert ios native app to convert to web app because the client have a master piece application which can only see html5 app pdf files or any web app.

So is there anyway to convert the ios native app to web app

Answer (score 1):

I dont think this is possible. You will have to recode it as a web app. There is no objective-C -> html5 converter.